# Method output giving wrong output

Tags: java, methods

```
public class Pow {

    public double getAnswer(double a, double b) {

        double b2 = 0;

        if (b > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < b; i++) {
                a = a * a;
            }
            return a;
        } else if (b < 0) {
            int c = 0;
            while (c > b) {
                a = a * a;
                c--;
            }
            b2 = 1 / a;
        }
        return b2;
    }
}
```

I need the second part of my method to return the value of a negative power(i.e. 5^-2 = .04), but the output is always 0. The first part of the method works fine from what I have tested. I do have the last curly braces but they just wouldn't fit in the text box on here. Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This code works as expected

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey [not quite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70139790/256196)!

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey What if b < 0? What if b == 0? What if b is has a floating point value?

Answer (score 3):

Running your code does *not* produce `0` as a result, but there is a bug.

`a = a * a` *squares* the number every iteration, so a<sup>n</sup> will be calculated as: a<sup>2<sup>n-1</sup></sup>.

Try accumulating the multiplication in a different variable:

```
double b2 = 0;
double result = 1;

if (b > 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
        result *= a;
    }
    return result;
} else if (b < 0) {
    int c = 0;
    while (c > b) {
        result *= a;
        c--;
    }
    b2 = 1 / result;
}
return b2;
```

Comment: YES, thank you so much that makes sense. That worked perfectly. I can't thank you enough man! Much love!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Pow {

    public double getAnswer(double a, double b) {

        double b2 = 0;

        if (b > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < b; i++) {
                a = a * a;
            }
            return a;
        } else if (b < 0) {
            return getAnswer(a, -b);
        }
        return 1; // b is 0
    }
```

Your algorithm for (b < 0) was wrong. If b < 0, the calculation is 1 / a^(-b).

Why your parameter `b` is of type `double`? What if `b` is 2.5? I suggest to change the type of `b` to `int` or you have to change your algorithm.

Comment: Noted. I'm tried changing the values to integers, but the output was the same, but I do see what issue you bring up. I'm not sure how I would go about that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @WhoUsedMyName Just change b to `int` and don't forget that there are THREE possible cases: b > 0, b == 0, b < 0

Answer (score 0):

As Bohemian♦ said

`a = a * a;`

squares `a` each time.

What we want is for a (the base) to be multiplied by itself b (the power) times.

Since the only difference between `a` to the power of `b` and `a` to the power of `(-b)` is that the latter is the 1 / the former, we can use quite nearly the same code for both negative and positive exponents.

Code:

```cpp
public double getAnswer(double a, double b) {//a is the base, b is the power

    double a2 = 1;
    double b2 = 0;

    if (b > 0) {//for positive powers
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {//a needs to be multiplied by itself (b) times
            a2 = a2 * a;
        }
        return a2;
    }
    else if (b < 0) {//for negative powers 
        for (int i = 0; i < -b; i++) {//a still needs to be multiplied by itself (-b) times, but since b is negative, we increment up to the opposite of b
            a2 = a2 * a;
        }
        return 1 / a2;//finally, since the power (b) is negative, we need to return 1 / (a2)
    }
}
```

Comment: DRY - don't repeat yourself (b < 0)